# How to build more effective design for sqlite operations

Tags: android, database, sqlite, oop

I am working on sqlite and android app. There is a xml file, i take the information of database, tables, tables count, column types... When app is starts, all tables should be created. There is no specific count of tables and the table columns. So I should design a percect dynamic structure. Actually I did too thing; Dynamic sqlquery for unknown tables count... Left some easy thing.

My constructor ;

```
public Database(Context context,String tablename, String [] a) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.tables=a;
        this.TABLE_NAME=tablename;
    }
```

My query builder, not matter how many tables count and types...

```
private String querybuild(String [] ss){
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0;i<ss.length;i++){

            if( i % 2 == 0){    
         stringBuilder.append(ss[i]);
         stringBuilder.append(" ");
            }   
            if(i % 2 == 1){
                 stringBuilder.append(ss[i]);    
                 if(i!=ss.length-1)
                 stringBuilder.append(",");

                    }
         }

        String finalString = stringBuilder.toString();
        return  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                +finalString+")";
    }
```

It is onCreate method. May be i should call second time, i dont know...

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(querybuild(tables));
    }
```

So there is point. Where app is created, the codes is here;

```
 SQLiteDatabase dbp= new Database(getApplicationContext(),"table1",new String[]{ "ID","INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT","cola","TEXT NOT NULL","colb","TEXT"}).getWritableDatabase();

     SQLiteDatabase dbc= new Database(getApplicationContext(),"table2",new String[]{ "_ID","INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT","col1","TEXT NOT NULL","col2","TEXT","col3","TEXT"}).getWritableDatabase();
```

The first dbp variable is working, that is creates table name of tables1. But the second variable dbc does not creates table. So my design is not good...

I know the database version for onupgrade. But already app is starting new and i want created all tables in first time. Should i call the onCreate method second time? Or should i change the database version and use onupgrade? What is the way?

Answer (score 0):

`SQLiteOpenHelper` is intended to be used for a database whose structure is known.

Anyway, your problem is that you're using `onCreate` wrong; its responsibility is to create the entire database.
So you have to handle all tables in there:

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // ... get list of tables ...
    for (each table) {
        db.execSQL(querybuild(table));
    }
}
```

If you cannot write `onCreate` this way, then you cannot use `SQLiteOpenHelper` and must use a plain `SQLiteDatabase` object directly.

Comment: There is no way get list of tables in first time. So in my design. it should be , when i want create table, i add new Database variable... Sory, may be your way the way. but i dont understand.

Comment: So i can not call oncreate method second time. i think, onCreate creates all tables in one times... If that true then like you said, i should get list of tables. Okay. Well, can you give mi a idea? How can set all tables for onCreate in my design. May be should make an array of arrays... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

is there any help?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // ... get list of tables ...
    for (each table) {
        db.execSQL(querybuild(table));
    }
}
```

how it is possible?